# Trying to create a trigger to update Sum Table

Tags: mysql, triggers, sum

I am new to triggers and have an idea that may speed up my query.
I have a table called labour, which has Id (Primary Key, AI), Job_No, Date, Paying_Rate and Working_Hrs
I have a table called Sum which has Id (Primary Key, AI), Job_No and Total_Labour
So when a new line gets added to labour or updated, I want it to insert the sum into the Sum table.
So I am thinking along these lines.
When labour added Select Sum (Paying_Rate*Working_Hrs)AS Sum, then insert that into the sum table, Total_Labour as per Job_No.
Then when another new labour is added, with the same Job_No the same query runs, but it updates the Total_Labour in the Sum table.

Looking at it like a table view.
***Labour***

| Id | Job_No | Date | Paying_Rate | Working_Hrs | Calculated AS Sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 |  | 10.00 | 10 | 100.00 |
| 2 | 1000 |  | 20.00 | 4 | 80.00 |

***Sum***

| Id | Job_No | Total_Labour |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 | 180.00 |

Is what I am trying possible?

Thank you

Comment: Stop and just **don't**. Data should be kept redundancy free to avoid the possibilities of inconsistencies. So writing sum over one table into another isn't a good thing to do. If you need the sum, you can always query it and get the **right** result. For convenience you can create a view that stores such a query so you don't have to repeat it every time.

Comment: OK Thanks. That is what I am doing at present.

Comment: Do not describe your tables in words, provide their CREATE TABLE scripts. Provide sample data as INSERT INTO script and desired output for this sample data. PS. I agree with @stickybit completely.